# ORACLE Computed and Automatic Columns

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, calculated-columns

I found this document on the official ORACLE page while searching for information on  Computed/Automatic/Virtual Columns:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/rdb/automatic-columns-132042.pdf
(Title: "Guide to Using SQL: Computed and Automatic Columns. A feature of Oracle Rdb")

Can anyone tell of these features really exist in ORACLE (I'm using version 10g, the document says Computed/Automatic is there since 7.1)?
I can't get any of the examples to work. Also the SQL formatting and syntax highlighting with ORACLE SQL Developer (v 3.0.04) does not work on these statements.

The document does not state that it is a tech-preview or something like that and according to the last page it has been around since May 2002.

For me it reads like a very early preview of 11g's VIRTUAL COLUMNS. What do you think?

Thanks,
Blama

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're reading the documentation of another product: [Rdb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Rdb) (this is not *Oracle Database Server*)!